# How to create an array inside an object when working with MongoDB using Django?

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, nested, djongo

I am working on a project where I want my user model to have this structure:

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"61bf3e026ffc7993a082773e"
   },
   "email":"user@domain.com",
   "role":"student",
   "type":"t1",
   "fname":"ABC",
   "from":{
      "org-user":[
         "83bf3e026ffc7993a0827731",
         "78bf3e026ffc7993a0827731"
      ]
   }
}
```

In this model, `from` is the object which has one key `org-user`. This `org-user` is an array of mongodb object IDs.

This is the code I have written so far.

```
from djongo import models


class User(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "users"

    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    role = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="student")
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="internal")
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

any idea on how I can achieve this in Django?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on djongos `models.ArrayField`, something like

```
class User(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "users"

    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    role = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="student")
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="internal")
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    # something like that
    org_user = models.ArrayField(
        model_container=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    )
```

Read more about that here [MongoDB ArrayField](https://www.djongomapper.com/using-django-with-mongodb-array-field/).

You also could try `python manage.py inspect_db User > models_file.py`, but I dont know what djongo can do here, to automatically generate the models from an existing database.